# Cannot find value for implicit parameters (extensible records)

Tags: scala, record, shapeless, hlist

I have a function that looks like the following:

```
def fun[T <: HList](l: T)(implicit k: HKernelAux[T], ft: FromTraversable[T]) = ???
```

This function works when I pass an argument of type `HList`. If I pass an extensible record, which is just a `HList` with labels, values for the implicit parameters cannot be found. Why is that? Is there a way such that the function works for `HList`s and extensible records or can I provide another function which works on extensible records?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is that instance of `Typeable` is not found for `` FieldType[Witness.`'key`.T, ValueType] ``.

Try to modify the function:

```
import shapeless.{HList, HNil}
import shapeless.ops.hlist.HKernelAux
import shapeless.ops.traversable.FromTraversable
import shapeless.ops.record.Values

def fun[T <: HList, T1 <: HList](l: T)(implicit v: Values.Aux[T, T1], k: HKernelAux[T1],  ft: FromTraversable[T1]) = {
  //use l.values instead of l
}
```

Usage:

```
import shapeless.syntax.singleton._
fun('a ->> 1 :: 'b ->> "x" :: HNil) // compiles
```

Comment: I will use UnzipFields to get the keys and values. Is there a type class that can reverse UnzipFields?

Comment: What do you mean by "reverse"?

Comment: Take the HList for the keys and the HList for the values and combine them into a record.

Comment: Try `shapeless.ops.hlist.Zip`

Comment: But it takes not two hlists, it takes hlist of hlists.

Comment: Two hlists can be transformed into hlist of them.

Comment: Since you need to pack pairs `(key, value)` into `key ->> value` it's better to use `shapeless.ops.hlist.ZipWith`.

Comment: This can be done automatically with `shapeless.ops.hlist.ZipWithKeys`.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I just found ZipWithKeys myself :)